# My variable always becomes a zero

Tags: c++, variables, zero, square-root

I have a problem with my C++ code where Im doing two steps in one with regards to pythagoras.

Im getting the length of a and b at the same time as doing the pythagoras function but my variable always equals 0 even though the X and Y points show up with their respective values.

Unfortunatly due to this when square rooting the resut it procceds with an error as you cannot square root 0.

It looks kinda complicated but this was the neatest I could get it

```
hypPrevious = ( 
                ( *(previousCalcp->getX()) - *(currentCalcp->getX()) ) 
                *   
                ( *(previousCalcp->getX()) - *(currentCalcp->getX()) )
              ) 
              +
              ( 
                ( *(currentCalcp->getY()) - *(previousCalcp->getY()) ) 
                *   
                ( *(currentCalcp->getY()) - *(previousCalcp->getY()) )
              );
```

Comment: If the current X and previous X are the same number you will get 0. 0 * 0 is 0.

Comment: Check if the pointers are equal: previousCalcp == currentCalcp. And wy do you use pointers?

Comment: Why can't you square root 0?

Comment: I thought that but If it helps the co ordinates should be like this

current X: 4 Y: 8
previous Y: X 8 Y: 9

Comment: I'll check the pointers, and I have to use pointers as its part of a method which links to another class. just passing a pointer is faster than a whole object

Comment: Faster in what way? Using pointers makes your code harder to read and more likely to have bad pointers.

Comment: Just to be sure, because this is unusual. Do functions getX() and getY() return pointers to coordinates?

Comment: why don't store the values instead of wasting time recalculating the results like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the information you gave us, the best advice I can give you is rewriting your code and add a debugging line to check what is going wrong:

```
int x1 = *(previousCalcp->getX());
int y1 = *(previousCalcp->getY())
int x2 = *(currentCalcp->getX());
int y2 = *(currentCalcp->getY());
int dx = x1 - x2;
int dy = y1 - y2;
hypPrevious = dx*dx + dy*dy;
std::cout << "(" << x1 << "," << y1 << ") and (" << x2 << "," << y2 << ") resulted in " << hypPrevious << std::endl;
```

Don't forget to change the type `int` to whatever you are using in your code.

Comment: This is probably a good idea, Its getting a little confusing... Sorry if this sounds silly but i've used cout many times, but what does it do when you put 'std::' in front?

Comment: You have to add `std::` when you do not use `using namespace std;` and minimize namespace pollution.